# Как в ex-mode (vim) в Atom добавить команды?

Tags: vim, atom

В ex-mode в Atom, по-моему, есть вообще только две команды (:w, :q).

В документации написано: используйте сервис, чтобы зарегистрировать команды из своего пакета, или прямо из init.coffee.

Не понимаю где мой пакет. Где регистрировать команды и как?

Answer (score 1):

согласно [документации к программе *atom*](http://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/sections/the-init-file/), инициализационный файл `init.coffee` разыскивается программой *atom* в каталоге `~/.atom`.

если такого файла там нет, можно его создать.

этот файл интерпретируется программой *atom* после окончания её загрузки.

в [документации к пакету *ex-mode*](https://atom.io/packages/ex-mode) написано, что примеры находятся в файле `lib/ex.coffee`. это относительный путь из каталога с этим пакетом. т.е., `~/.atom/packages/ex-mode/lib/ex.coffee`.

там же, в документации, приведён и пример конфигурации, которую и надо вставить непосредственно в вышеупомянутый инициализационный файл `init.coffee`.